# Why Parse.User.current() is null?

Tags: javascript, authentication, parse-platform

I have the following query, my application has 2 types of users
administrator and collaborator.
I am currently programming the administrator profile, where only he can add new employees and dividing by departments. My problem is with permissions
I can not get any data, even though I have defined the administrator can.

When I print in Parse.User.current (console), the result is "null"

Greetings .. :)

Comment: Has a user logged in?

Comment: yes this happen after the user has logged

Answer (score 1):

There is a mistake in the syntax, it should be `console.info(Parse.User.current())` not `Parse.User.current` (console)

Comment: I have done it for you for now. Remember for next time.